# How to insert an intenger number in a String with method push()

Tags: java, arrays, methods, netbeans

I want to put the value "restante" in my string array with method push. But an error display:

`incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String`

My JAVA file

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumRestantes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pilha p1 = new Pilha(10);
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valor;
        int restante;
        
        valor = ler.nextInt();
        
        restante = valor%16;
        try {
            if (restante == 0) {
                p1.push(new Numeros(restante, 0));
            } else {
                while(restante >= 1) {
                    restante = restante%16;
                    p1.push(new Numeros(restante, 0));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know much about methods, so I'd want some help to push values from variable "restante" to my array string.

Comment: `Integer.toString(restante))`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the `int` to a `String`, then add it. One way to do this is to use `Integer.toString(int)`. This uses the `Integer` class to convert an `int` into a string containing the `int`.